# Error when combining "skip" with other patterns

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I want to create a turtle pattern that is the equivalent of a  "lookbefore" in Regex. From the docs, it looks like this can work, using the `skip` pattern e.g like this:

`match (skip "key:" <> chars) "key:value" -- "value"`

But I get a type error

```
<interactive>:34:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘()’
      Expected: Pattern ()
        Actual: Pattern Text
    • In the second argument of ‘(<>)’, namely ‘chars’
      In the first argument of ‘match’, namely ‘(skip "key: " <> chars)’
      In the expression: match (skip "key: " <> chars) "key:value"
```

How can I make this work, and if not, is  there another way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: so you want to skip `key`, and just return `"value"`?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by first running the `skip` parser, and then return the value for `chars`, so:

```
match (skip "key: " *> chars) "key:value"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you add some description of how this whole thing works? What's `*>`? I used `>==>` when using parser combinator libraries, is this similar?

Comment: Also, the use of skip is redundant here, it is more correct to type it as 
`match ((text "key: ") *> chars) "key:value"`

Answer (score 0):

`<>` is the wrong combining operator to use for this case.

[`skip "key: "`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.6.2/docs/Turtle-Pattern.html#v:skip) is a `Pattern ()`. [`chars`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.6.2/docs/Turtle-Pattern.html#v:chars) is a `Pattern Text`.

`<>` comes from the [`Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) class, where we can see that `<>` has type `a -> a -> a` (for some type `a` with a `Semigroup` instance, which `Pattern` has); it combines two things of the same type. So specialised to turtle's `Pattern` type, the `<>` operator is `Pattern a -> Pattern a -> Pattern a`<sup>1</sup>. You could use it to combine two `Pattern ()` values (to get a `Pattern ()`), or you could use it to combine two `Pattern Text` values (to get a `Pattern Text`). It doesn't know how to combine two *different* `Pattern` types.

Thinking about it more intuitively (rather than looking at the types), `<>` combines two patterns into one larger pattern by combining their matched results (also by using the `<>` operator). But here you don't want to combine the results of your patterns, you want to *ignore* the result of the `skip "key: "` pattern and have the result of the combined pattern just be the result of the `chars` pattern. So we come to the same conclusion: `<>` isn't an operator that does what you want.

Willem's answer suggested the `*>` operator. That comes from [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative), and [has type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-) `f a -> f b -> f b` (for some type constructor `f` with an `Applicative` instance, which `Pattern` has). Specialised to `Pattern` this is `Pattern a -> Pattern b -> Pattern b`; it combines two patterns but the result type `a` from the first pattern doesn't appear in the final resulting type `Pattern b`. Specialised to the types of your two patterns, it would end up being `Pattern () -> Pattern Text -> Pattern Text`, which is what you need.

---

<sup>1</sup> Provided whatever type is chosen for `a` is also a `Semigroup`.